# GoDaddy Certs in Java Keystore Producing "ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" in Chrome

Tags: java, ssl

I have a Java intranet web application that can apply SSL from a Java keystore. I first created the keystore and its private key entry with this command:

```
keytool -keystore "filename.p12" -storetype PKCS12 -storepass password -genkey -alias aliasname -keypass password -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 365
```

And then I generated a CSR with this:

```
keytool -certreq -keystore "filename.p12" -storetype PKCS12 -storepass password -alias aliasname -keyalg rsa -file csr.txt
```

We keyed a new cert with GoDaddy using that CSR, and exported them as the "Other" format. This gave us a .crt cert and a .crt bundle (among one or two other pem files I think).

I've tried importing just the cert as well as the bundle and cert, using the -trustcacerts flag and without. I've tried including the root cert from the GoDaddy repository, as well as importing it into MMC Trusted Root Certification Authorities store. The browser error is that the cert authority is invalid, and when I view the cert details from the browser it says "The CA Root certificate is not trusted  because it is not in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store".

Having set up SSL for this application dozens of times, this one is a first. Any ideas?

Comment: So have you tried to move the CA Root certificate to the Trusted Certificate Authorities store on your unspecified OS?

Comment: Yes, I should have pointed out that this is Windows Server (2016 I believe, not my server). I did mention in the second to last paragraph that I'd imported it into the store.

Comment: You are getting the certificate error within the browser on the server or the client viewing the server? How are you going to solve this issue if it required a server configuration change?

Comment: I'm seeing the error in both. I'm not sure what you mean by requiring a server configuration change; I've just been troubleshooting the keystore and the certs themselves.